# Removing shorter strings not working

Tags: java

Write a method `removeShorterStrings` that takes an `ArrayList<String>` as a parameter and that removes from each successive pair of values the shorter string in the pair.

For example, suppose that an `ArrayList` called `list` contains the following values: `{"four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"}`

In the first pair, `"four"` and `"score"`, the shorter string is `"four"`.
In the second pair, `"and"` and `"seven"`, the shorter string is `"and"`.
In the third pair, `"years"` and `"ago"`, the shorter string is `"ago"`.

Therefore, the call: `removeShorterStrings(list);` should remove these shorter strings, leaving the list as follows: `{"score", "seven", "years"}`.

If there is a tie (both strings have the same length), your method should remove the first string in the pair. If there is an odd number of strings in the list, the final value should be kept in the list.

```
public void removeShorterStrings(ArrayList <String> a){
   
    for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;i+=2){
        String word=a.get(i);
        String word2=a.get(i+1);
        
        if(a.size()%2==0 && word.length()<word2.length()){
           a.remove(i);
            if(word.length()==word2.length()){
                a.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

called for `["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"]`.

My code gives me `[score, and, seven, years, ago]` instead of `[score, seven, years]`.

What's the problem?

Comment: "Tips to do well in Java" does not fit on this site. Either reading an Intro To Programming or Intro To Java book (Google for a good one) or [taking](https://www.edx.org/) [a](https://www.udacity.com/) [course](https://www.coursera.org/) that explains things better may help. You may also be able to find a Logical Thinking book or course somewhere. Reading basic programming blogs may also help.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already removing your items from the list you only need to increment by one. And since your compare pairs, you need to remove one of them in your loop.

This one produces [score, seven, years]

```
public void removeShorterStrings(ArrayList <String> a){

    for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;i++){
        String word=a.get(i);
        String word2=a.get(i+1);

        if(word.length()<word2.length()){
           a.remove(i);           
        } else {
           a.remove(i+1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @baraky yes I ran it in groovyConsole `removeShorterStrings(["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"])`

Comment: Your loop body can be expressed in one line. You may consider edited out a lot of redundant code, especially declaring local variable for the words.

Comment: @Bohemian I know that this could be optimized, I wanted to show what changes were necessary to the original code to make it work, not build the optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your test `a.size()%2==0` is done for each pair, this is not required. Simply remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you remove elements from the list, but keep using the old indices. The easiest way to get past this is by traversing your array backwards:

```
public void removeShorterStrings(ArrayList <String> a){

    for(int i=a.size()/2-1; i>=0; i--){
        String word=a.get(2*i);
        String word2=a.get(2*i+1);

        if(word.length()<=word2.length()){
           a.remove(2*i);
        } else {
           a.remove(2*i+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot change a list inside a for loop iterating on the list elements.** (unless you handle the index after removing elements)

Lets say you remove the first element, (i=0), then the second element (index 1) becomes the first and so on.
Now, when you increment i, you get to the second pair, which was originally the forth and fifth (instead of third and forth).

Try to understand it first.

That's why you cant change a list when iterating over it (unless you use `Iterator`)

Another thing- you don't need to check if `a.size()%2==0`. There are many other ways you can do it.

Comment: Unless you move backwards :)

Comment: if you change `i+=2` by `++i` and add a `else { ++i; }` you can do `a.remove(i)`.

Comment: That's exactly "unless you handle the current index after removing elements"

Comment: unless i move backwards?You mean in the for loops it should be i--?

Comment: It can, or decrement i when removing an element.

Answer (score 0):

Take care you have main issues here

First

```
for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;i+=2){
```

you remove elements from a dynamic array (ArrayList) and you deal with it as if it is static one by incrementing i each iteration by 2 while you remove each iteration 1 element so indexes of elements are decreased by 2. 
i.e. in first iteration your i=0 and you remove "four" from a, so now a contains ["score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"], then you go for second loop with i=2 which makes a.get(i) return "seven" not "and" to you ! , that obvious because now you removed 1 element and esch element now have index=oldIndex-1.

Second

```
if(a.size()%2==0 && word.length()<word2.length()){
       a.remove(i);
        if(word.length()==word2.length()){
            a.remove(i);
        }
    }
```

you put totally wrong conditions in this if block and this is actually the main work you do here which will never be done correctly now because of these conditions.

1-`a.size()%2==0` will evaluate to true only in the first loop because size is even, after first loop you will have this even size decreased by 1 to become odd.

2-`word.length()<word2.length()` this will give false once the two words are equal in length !! actually you will never get to this condition `if(word.length()==word2.length()){
                a.remove(i);
            }`

correct code should be

```
for(int i=0;i<a.size()-1;i++){
        String word=a.get(i);
        String word2=a.get(i+1);

        if(word.length()<=word2.length()){
           a.remove(i);
        }
        else
           a.remove(i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void removeShorterStrings(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size()-1; i++){
        if(arrayList.get(i).length() <= arrayList.get(i + 1).length()){
            arrayList.remove(i);
        }
        else{
            arrayList.remove(i + 1);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

input: ["four", "score", "and", "seven", "years", "ago"]

output: [score, seven, years]